# How do I ask a good question? is this error?

Tags: pine-script

this is correct

```
sum1 = 0.00
for i = 1 to 2
    x = sma(close, 20)[1]
    sum1 := sum1 + x
plot(sum1)
```

and this is error

```
sum1 = 0.00
for i = 1 to 2
    x = sma(close, i)[1]
    sum1 := sum1 + x
plot(sum1)
```

this is why?My english is bad!
thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's an old problem - in a loop you cannot send an index (or something, that changes) value to a build-in function. Use pine implementation of the correspond functions. For example, for the `sum` you can find implementation here https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_sum

Comment: Please change the title of the question.  "How do I ask a good question?" should lead only to https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  Your question is not about asking a good question, it is about a `for` loop in `pine-script`